# linux shell find, compare and delete files

Tags: linux, file, shell, comparison

I have two directories, and in one of them I renamed a lot and now I have more than 2000 different files.

I'd like to find out all the files of the same size, do a CRC on files with identical sizes, and if they match, delete file from the second folder.

After googling, I found BeyondCompare and other nice diff utilities, but they dont do this.

I'm pretty sure a one-liner in a Linux shell could do this.

Comment: Good question : +1 for you, I will thinking which commands you have searched so far about solving this problem?

Comment: Until now I found that I could do a CRC like this: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cksum` and output it. Then I'll try to use `awk` to sort it with the second record (which is filesize)... then I'm stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dedicated tool, [fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes)

```
$ fdupes -rfd dir1 dir2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think this is what I need. But I dont get the point of omitting the first file ("-f" option).

Comment: If there's some copys, you need to keep one of them ;)

Comment: Ok so it prints *only* the duplicates, not the original. But what if the one I want to keep is the second one?

Comment: Will it check the content of the file, using some hashing algorithm? otherwise renamed files will be left there.

Comment: Yes, see https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes there's a md5 folder, and you can grep md5 in the source code after a git clone.

Answer (score 0):

Use an MD5 sum:

```
$ md5sum firstdir/* | sort > first.txt
$ md5sum secondidr/* | sort > second.txt
$ comm -12 first.txt second.txt | xargs rm
```

It is not a one-line command, but it shouldn't be difficult to combine these commands.

Comment: Just by using an `&&` you can keep all these commands together.

Comment: It doesn't work because md5sum outputs md5 checksum and the filename so no line matches.